# In Debian Using Android TV x86 Emulator Image with QEMU/KVM

Tags: linux-kvm, qemu, android-x86

If I am correct, Android Emulator uses KVM/QEMU for virtualization. Since there is no standalone Android TV x86 installer floating around I need to use these images to create myself a virtual Android TV. But I do not know how to do it.

What I want is possible or not? If it is possible can you guide me through a little bit, since I do not found anything on the Internet about this?

Thank you.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 It comes with Android Studio. The emulator downloads the images from some repository I guess. But if you need it I can upload it to Google Drive or something for inspection.